# Find out all Boost .lib files that are being used by my project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, msbuild, linker

I was able to successfully set-up my VS C++ 2017 project with pre-build BOOST binaries. Ran few test project and everything seems to be working fine. Now, I'm trying to build a release version with all the required BOOST `.lib` files in the `\Release`. Problem is, I don't know which `.lib` files linker is using.

Is there a way to find out which BOOST `.lib` linker is linking against ?
Edit: Boost doc. mentioned that VS(MSBuild) is using Auto-Linking, which makes things a lot easier.

Comment: I assume you are using automatic linking via #pragma comment(lib ..) from the boost headers.

Comment: @drescherjm To be honest, I'm not sure. All I did, is in Properties of project, set the path where header are (BOOST_ROOT directory) and set path for `.\lib` in `\lib32-msvc-14.1`

Comment: I don't know of an easy automatic way to do this.

Comment: Maybe you can use Dependency Walker to check the relationship, though this tool is old.(Or try some similar tool in github) And for boost_XXX-gd.dll and boost_XXX.dll, choose the latter one which is for release version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question.
@Lance Li-MSFT suggested setting verbosity to detailed, that didn't help.
What helped is passing flag to linker as cmd line argument in Visual Studio. Right click on project, Properties => Linker => Command Line and add flag `/VERBOSE:LIB`
It will list all the libraries which VS is searching and linking against.
Next step would be to copy the VS build output. Click somewhere in the output and `CTRL+S` to save the output to file. Search the file for .libs.

For more information ref. to `MSVC Linker Options` in MS documentation.

Comment: Sorry for that can't help. And do thank you for sharing your solution:)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know which .lib files linker is using.

Not familiar with boost. But for msbuild in Visual studio, `go Tools=>Options=>Projects and Solutions=>Build and Run`, change the `build verbosity` to `Detailed`.

After that, we can see detailed output message from msbuild which displays the process of msbuild. Maybe what you want is a 'link' target which provides details about the link process like below:

[image]

Hope it helps.